# Is a disarm with Weapon Finesse made with a Str or Dex bonus to CMB?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, ability-scores, combat-maneuver, disarming

If you are using a rapier with the feat Weapon Finesse while attempting to disarm an opponent, do you use DEX or STR on the CMB for the disarm attempt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use Dex. See [the FAQ on the d20PFSRD Weapon Finesse page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-finesse-combat-final/) or on the [Paizo FAQ list](http://paizo.com/products/btpy88yj/faq?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Core-Rulebook#v5748eaic9ojt):

> **If I have Weapon Finesse, can I apply my Dex bonus to my combat maneuver checks instead of my Strength bonus??**
>
> It depends on what combat maneuver you’re attempting. Disarm, sunder, and trip are normally the only kinds of combat maneuvers in which you’re actually using a weapon to perform the maneuver, and therefore the weapon’s bonuses apply to the roll. Therefore, *if you’re attempting a disarm*, sunder, or trip *maneuver, you can apply your Dex bonus instead of your Str mod on the combat maneuver check (assuming you’re using a finessable weapon, of course).* For other combat maneuvers, you use the normal rule for determining CMB ( Str instead of Dex).
>
> The Agile Maneuvers feat applies to all combat maneuvers, not just disarm, sunder, and trip, so it is still a useful option for a Dex-based creature that uses combat maneuvers.

<sup>(*emphasis* mine)</sup>